# Error in XSD without namespace

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, jaxb, xsd, xsd-validation

I have two XSDs to bottom, the following situation is, I'm consuming a REST service and rode two XSDs to generate classes via JAXB, it happens that I have to get the targetNamespace of the two XSDs, because it seems that the service has no namespace when consumption attributes is null, the JAXB generated class called package-info.java

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
```

Where I deleted the namespace as low (with XSDs with this target namespace), and it worked, but I have to take the XSDs, and in one of these I m using an element that points to the other. But giving this formatting error, I tried to import, but asks the namespace, both xsds are in the same directory

**Error:**

> src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'Block'. It was detected
>   that 'Block' is in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/  XMLSchema', but
>   components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema
>   document 'file:///G:/Dev/src/main/xsd/Actor.xsd'. If this is the
>   incorrect   namespace, perhaps the prefix of 'BlockList' needs to be
>   changed. If this is the correct namespace, then an appropriate
>   'import'   tag should be added to 'file:///G:/Dev/
>   src/main/xsd/Actor.xsd'.

**actor.xsd**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
     <include schemaLocation="Block.xsd"/>
     <complexType name="Actor">
      <sequence>
       <element name="type" type="string" maxOccurs="1"
        minOccurs="1">
       </element>
       <element name="blockList" type="Block"  maxOccurs="1"
        minOccurs="1"></element>
       <element name="characteristicList" maxOccurs="1"
        minOccurs="1">
        <complexType>
         <sequence>
          <element name="characteristic"
           maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
           <complexType>
            <sequence>
             <element name="id" type="long"></element>
             <element name="name"
              type="string">
             </element>
             <element name="value"
              type="string">
             </element>
            </sequence>
           </complexType>
          </element>
         </sequence>
        </complexType>
       </element>
      </sequence>
     </complexType>
    </schema>
```

**Block.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
 <complexType name="Block">
  <sequence>
   <element name="greyList" type="boolean"></element>
   <element name="blackList" type="boolean"></element>
   <element name="blockListTimeToExit" type="long"></element>
   <element name="blockedEventList">
    <complexType>
     <sequence>
      <element name="blockedEvent" type="string" maxOccurs="unbounded"
       minOccurs="0"></element>
     </sequence>
    </complexType>
   </element>
  </sequence>
 </complexType>
</schema>
```

Comment: have you solved this issue? if yes, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Change your XSDs in ...

**actor.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
   targetNamespace="yourNamespace" 
    xmlns:prefix="yourNamespace">
    <include schemaLocation="Block.xsd"/>
    <complexType name="Actor">
        <sequence>
            <element name="type" type="string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
       </element>
            <element name="blockList" type="prefix:Block" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"></element>
            <element name="characteristicList" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="characteristic" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
                            <complexType>
                                <sequence>
                                    <element name="id" type="long"></element>
                                    <element name="name" type="string">
             </element>
                                    <element name="value" type="string">
             </element>
                                </sequence>
                            </complexType>
                        </element>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

**Block.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="yourNamespace"
    xmlns:apm="yourNamespace">
    <complexType name="Block">
        <sequence>
            <element name="greyList" type="boolean"></element>
            <element name="blackList" type="boolean"></element>
            <element name="blockListTimeToExit" type="long"></element>
            <element name="blockedEventList">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="blockedEvent" type="string" maxOccurs="unbounded"
                            minOccurs="0">
                        </element>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

I added only the namespaces and prefix to use the type from the Block.xsd.